# Is there a possible way to access the latest document which is added to the firestore database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to access the latest document that is added to the database, So that with that `refID` I can add other field to the same document without overriding other documents.

Answer (score 2):

You can add timestamps of documents when you add them to the database, so when you want to access the latest one, just compare the timestamps.

When pushing you can use `Date.now()` for this.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to add information to documents as they are created, I think a better pattern would be to use a firebase function that triggers on creation of new documents in firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Otherwise, a order by timestamp and limit 1 should do the trick: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data